# Unable to get the average property of the worksheetfunction class

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm trying to write vba to help me convert daily data into weekly data. I wrote this vba but said `unable to get the average property of the worksheetfunction class`. Is it possible someone can help me figure whats wrong? thanks!

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim z As Integer

  For z = 0 To 2000

   Set Rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("D5:D11").Offset(7 * z, 0)

    Range("runningagain").Offset(z, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Rng1)

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

  Next z

End Sub
```

Comment: You may need to check Rng1 is not empty.  `If WorksheetFunction.Count(rng1) > 0 Then ..... = WorksheetFunction.Average(rng1)`

Comment: @ooo They do need to check this, and using Count() is a neat way. You should put this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The average function in Excel will produce a #DIV/0! error if the cells are empty so you need to check `rng1` is not empty.

As you are taking the average then it's best to use Count instead of CountA

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Rng1) > 0 Then
    Range("runningagain").Offset(z, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Rng1)
End If
```

Also, you may need to define `Range("runningagain")` properly, do you mean `Range(runningagain)`?

Comment: thank you it works!i already defined them in my worksheet! thank you so much